# SQL - bucket an integer column and count each bucket

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have an integer column like below.

```
ID
---
1
2
3
..
..
99
100
```

I want to bucket this by 10 rows.

```
100 rows/10 buckets = 10 different buckets
```

I want to count the no of rows from each bucket.

```
id    | total rows
----------------
1-10  | 10
11-20 | 10
21-30 | 10
...   | ..
...   | ..
91-100| 10
```

Im trying to implement this with Postgresql and MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mysql:

```
select
    concat(min((id-1) div 10) * 10 + 1, '-', min((id-1) div 10) * 10 + 10) 'id',
    count(id) 'total rows'
from yourtable
group by (id-1) div 10
```

In postgres:

```
select
    (min((id-1) / 10) * 10 + 1) || '-' || (min((id-1) / 10) * 10 + 10) as id,
    count(id) as total_rows
from yourtable
group by (id-1) / 10
order by (id-1) / 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `truncate` function as follows:

```
Select concat(min(id),'-',max(id)) as ids, count(1) as total_rows
  From your_table t
Group by truncate(id-1, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using case expression

```
select case 
        when id between 1 and 10 then '1-10'
        when id between 11 and 20 then '11-20'
        when id between 21 and 30 then '21-30' end as id, count(*) as total_rows
from tablename
group by case 
          when id between 1 and 10 then '1-10'
          when id between 11 and 20 then '11-20'
          when id between 21 and 30 then '21-30' end
```

Answer (score 0):

In both Postgres and MySQL, the following should work:

```
select concat_ws('-', ceiling(id / 10.0) * 10 - 9, ceiling(id / 10.0) * 10) as id_range,
       count(*)
from t
group by id_range
order by min(id);
```

In addition to being the same in both databases, I also think this is perhaps the simplest construct in either database.

Here are two db<>fiddles:  for [Postgres](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d402ff0e112464fd0ee01ce6864c4365) and for [MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e52f31da457a53a97d40d386c374bf2e).