# BigQuery - count(*) of Range of IDs

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Im trying to run a select query on Googe BigQuery to group 100000 rows and count(*) the rows in that range.

#### Sample rows:

```
ID
1
2
3
...
100
101
...
100000
```

I want to group these IDs into 10000 rows bucket.

#### EX:

- Bucket 1 - 1 to 10000 ID
- Next - 10001 to 20000

At the same time, I want the number of rows in each bucket in the table.

I tried the sample code from [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65282965/sql-bucket-an-integer-column-and-count-each-bucket)(which worked for MySQL and Postgres), but in BQ, the `count(*)`  is not doing a count of the bucket, instead its doing individual rows.

#### Query I used:

```sql
select concat(min((id-1) / 10000) * 10000+ 1) || '-' || (min((id-1) / 10000) * 10000+ 10000) as id,
    count(*) as total_rows
from mytbl
group by (id-1) / 10000
order by (id);
```

#### Expected output:

```
id          | total rows
----------------
1-10000     | 10000
10001-20000 | 10000
20001-30000 | 8000 (if 2000 ids are not there in (where id between 20001 and 30000))
...         | ..
...         | ..
90001-100000| 10000
```

Comment: `count(*)` works the same in BQ as in other databases.  Your query should be doing what you want, assuming there are 8,000 rows in the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the range of the bucket, how about using this?

```
10000 as bucket_range
```

The number is constant.  The `count(*)` is the number of rows that fall into the range.

Comment: I didn't get it, where should I use this?

Answer (score 0):

You have used wrong `group by`. You should use `trunc` with the divison.

```
select concat(min(trunc((id-1) / 100000000)) * 100000000 + 1),
              '-', 
             (min(trunc((id-1) / 100000000)) * 100000000 + 100000000
             ) as id,
    count(*) as total_rows
from mytbl
group by trunc((id-1) / 100000000);
```

Also, you have used `concat` with some issue. I have corrected it in the answer.

Comment: Its giving me some strange output format. (https://ibb.co/RbNgGjb) Cancat - its spliting the column into 3 columns and INT column values looks like decimal

Comment: Use trunc there also. I have updated the answer, please check.

Comment: Got it, but still the 2nd value after the `'-'`  is showing something like `1.03E10` Any idea about this

Comment: Are you talking about - `(min(trunc((id-1) / 100000000)) * 100000000 + 100000000` ? It is not possible as you re adding 100000000 to your expression explicitly.